# How to Update post_modified of all wordpress post

Tags: php, sql

i want to update all my wordpress post modified date and time to a specific date and time,
i have a code to update it base on the id, but i want one to update all the row at once without putting the id of the posts .

```php
$sql = "UPDATE Zulu_posts SET post_modified='2020-11-17 16:06:00' WHERE id=2";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem does it solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generalized update query. As always, when dealing with databases **take a backup first**.

With that out of the way, your query should look something like:

```sql
BEGIN; -- Start a transaction
UPDATE
  wp_posts
SET
  post_modified = <Your new date>
  AND post_modified_gmt = <Your new date in GMT>;

SELECT * FROM wp_posts LIMIT 10 ORDER BY post_date DESC; -- See the 10 most recently authored posts, make sure their post_modified and post_modified_gmt looks good

COMMIT; -- Commit the changes to the database or
ROLLBACK; -- If things don't look right.
```

**Edit**: in your case, if you do this in PHP, **definitely** take a backup, and then make `$sql` everything above except for the lines with `BEGIN`, `COMMIT`, and `ROLLBACK`, though I'd recommend doing this in the command line or a GUI/web interface.

Comment: bro please i am getting errors, running it with queries, and as while i tried running it on php same thing, please can you  specify the code to run it on php.
thanks alot for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE zulu_posts SET post_modified_gmt = '2020-11-17-04:00:00'";
$sql = "UPDATE zulu_posts SET post_modified = '2020-11-17-04:00:00'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Ok bro this one worked, but i could like to add a form where by i can input the date and time i want and submit.
Please any idea on how i can do it